# Rename the column every time in PySpark if it is coming with different name in some files?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rename, pyspark-schema

I have to rename the column name every time if column name contains `address` in it.

For example, for the first file I am receiving columns as `ADDRESS1`, `ADDRESS2`, `ADDRESS3`:
[image]

For the next file I am receiving column names as `T_ADDRESS1`, `T_ADDRESS2`, `TADDRESS3`:
[image]

As I will write this code only once and pass it in my pipeline, how can I change the column name every time if it contains `ADDRESS` in it using PySpark? As in screenshots we can see, every time if name contains `address` in it we have to rename to `S_ADDRESS1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Python function like this could rename dataframe columns:

```py
import re
def df_rename(df):
    return df.toDF(*[re.sub(r"^(.*?)(?=ADDRESS)", "S_", c) for c in df.columns])
```

Test input dataframes:

```py
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([], "c1 int, ADDRESS1 int, ADDRESS2 int, ADDRESS3 int")
df1.show()
# +---+--------+--------+--------+
# | c1|ADDRESS1|ADDRESS2|ADDRESS3|
# +---+--------+--------+--------+
# +---+--------+--------+--------+

df2 = spark.createDataFrame([], "c1 int, T_ADDRESS1 int, T_ADDRESS2 int, T_ADDRESS3 int")
df2.show()
# +---+----------+----------+----------+
# | c1|T_ADDRESS1|T_ADDRESS2|T_ADDRESS3|
# +---+----------+----------+----------+
# +---+----------+----------+----------+
```

Applying the function:

```py
df1 = df_rename(df1)
df1.show()
# +---+----------+----------+----------+
# | c1|S_ADDRESS1|S_ADDRESS2|S_ADDRESS3|
# +---+----------+----------+----------+
# +---+----------+----------+----------+

df2 = df_rename(df2)
df2.show()
# +---+----------+----------+----------+
# | c1|S_ADDRESS1|S_ADDRESS2|S_ADDRESS3|
# +---+----------+----------+----------+
# +---+----------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Your code is working exactly the same i wanted.

Comment: suppose column name is coming as S_ADDRESS only in that case what can i use to avoid this in code. by your code it will add S_ again. can you help me with this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you don't want, just don't use this function. Either way the name of the column would stay S_ADDRESS